# Ckeditor detach/attach event

Tags: 7, javascript, wysiwyg

How can I execute/insert a jQuery script when disabling and enabling Ckeditor `Source` button.

I want to replace the image tag with a custom tag when detaching the ckeditor then bring back the original image tag when I attached the ckeditor back.

Ex:

```
<img alt="INLINE:143219;w=240;h=240" class="wysiwyg-inline-image" src="/sites/default/files/styles/inline_image_temp_240x240/public/2013/06/02/il_fullxfull.26370659.jpg?itok=-RT7n2ir" />
```

To:

```
<!-- INLINE:143219;w=240;h=240 -->
```

The replaced tag is based on the alt of the image being attached.

EDIT:

Here is my code so far:

```
    Drupal.behaviors.ckeditor_travel = {
      attach: function(context) {
        $('#cke_8').click(function () {
          Drupal.ck_inline.ckeditorInline();
        });
      }
    };



    Drupal.cnngo_inline.ckeditorInline = function() {

    var $content = CKEDITOR.instances['edit-body-und-0-value'].getData();

    if ($('#cke_1_contents textarea').length) {
      // console.log("Editor disabled");

      /**
       * Replace images with <!-- INLINE:xxx;w=x;h=x --> tags in content upon detaching editor.
       */
      $.each($('img.wysiwyg-inline-image', $content), function (i, elem) {
                altText = ' ' + Drupal.checkPlain(elem.getAttribute('alt')) + ' ';

                if (elem.parentNode && elem.parentNode.parentNode && elem.parentNode.tagName == 'H2') {
                    // Moving the current element to left side of H2 tag 
                    elem.parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createComment(altText), elem.parentNode);
                    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
                }
                else {
                  elem.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createComment(altText), elem);
                    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
                }
            });

            return CKEDITOR.instances['edit-body-und-0-value'].setData($content);
      //$(iframe).contents().find('body').find('img').replaceWith('<p><br class="clear-both"></p>');
    }

    if ($('#cke_1_contents iframe').length) {
      //console.log("Editor enabled");
      // Replace inline images with physical image
      content = content.replace(new RegExp('<!-- INLINE:([0-9]*);w=([0-9]*);h=([0-9]*) -->', 'gi'), function($0, $1, $2, $3) { return that.Drupal.ckeditor_inline.getPlaceholder($1, $2, $3); });

      return content;
    }
  };

  Drupal.ckeditor_inline.getPlaceholder = function(fid, w, h) {
    if (!fid) {
      fid = '';
    }
    if (!w) {
      w = '240';
    }
    if (!h) {
      h = '240';
    }

    // Grab image detail data
    var imgData = Drupal.ckeditor_inline.getInlineImageDetail(fid, w, h);

    // Build and return image tag
    return '<img src="' + imgData.src + '" alt="' + imgData.alt + '" title="' + imgData.title + '" class="wysiwyg-inline-image" width="' + w + '" height="' + h + '" />';
  }
```

The above is still not replacing the content in textarea, The `return CKEDITOR.instances['edit-body-und-0-value'].setData($content);` in detaching the editor is still returns the original content.

**UPDATE:**

I already figured out the attach/detach, however I'm facing a new problem which is I think is beyond my knowledge.

Any idea how to get the whole content/data in the wysiwyg using dataProcessor.dataFilter/htmlFilter method?

Code below is working, but only comment content is available without the comment tag (), so I can't replace the comment to the desired markup.

```
afterInit: function (editor) {
  var dataProcessor = editor.dataProcessor;
  var dataFilter = dataProcessor && dataProcessor.dataFilter;
  if (dataFilter) {
    dataFilter.addRules({
      comment: function (element) {
        that = Drupal.behaviors.inline_plugins;
        // Replace inline images with physical image
        element = element.replace(new RegExp('<!-- INLINE:([0-9]*);w=([0-9]*);h=([0-9]*) -->', 'gi'), function($0, $1, $2, $3) { return that._getPlaceholder($1, $2, $3); });
        return element; //<!-- <img src=123 /> --> should be <img src=123 />

      }
    });
  }
}
```